# The network dataset has no edge elements. It may be unbuilt. issue when trying to make a Service Area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, network-analyst, error-030024

Using ArcGIS Pro 3.0.0

I am currently attempting to create a Service Area of several stores and the road network although the error of "The network dataset has no edge elements. It may be unbuilt." keeps on pestering me. I have tried following attempts to fix it:

- Fixed geometry of  the roads. (According to official Esri Guide on how to deal with it)
- Moved the facilites so they have a contact with road.
- Dissolved all roads into one.

The edges generate properly, as I can see and everytime I tried those attempts I remade the Network Database And it  generates "ERROR 030024: Solve returned a failure." constantly. When making the ND, I only put roads and nothing else, and when importing points for the facilities I use ID's for the name.